# Azure Policy Support for Port Ranges

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Problem - so I want to block people creating NSGs that open up Internet access to some ports (22, 3389, etc.). I can create a policy to block the specific port, e.g.,

```
{
"allOf": [{
        "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/access",
        "equals": "Allow"
    },
    {
        "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/direction",
        "equals": "Inbound"
    },
    {
        "anyOf": [{
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
                "equals": "22"
            },
            {
                "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
                "equals": "3389"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This will block creation of NSGs if the specific port is used in the security rules. But it can be bypassed if someone create a NSG rules that allows port ranges (such as 3300-3400).

Wondering how policy deals with port ranges and what the best way is in this case.

I tried destinationPortRanges[*] array but it does not work.

```
{
"not": {
    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
    "Equals": "22"
}
```

}

the rule still allows creation of NSGs when destinationPortRanges is specified as "20-25".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the built-in policy "[RDP access from the Internet should be blocked](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Network/NetworkSecurityGroup_RDPAccess_Audit.json)".
There is also [SSH access from the Internet should be blocked](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Network/NetworkSecurityGroup_SSHAccess_Audit.json).

To be honest it is quite painful to read, but it looks like it covers exactly what you need.

```
{
                "anyOf": [
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
                    "equals": "*"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange",
                    "equals": "3389"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "[if(and(not(empty(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'))), contains(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'),'-')), and(lessOrEquals(int(first(split(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'), '-'))),3389),greaterOrEquals(int(last(split(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRange'), '-'))),3389)), 'false')]",
                    "equals": "true"
                  },
                  {
                      "count": {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
                        "where": {
                          "value": "[if(and(not(empty(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')))), contains(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')),'-')), and(lessOrEquals(int(first(split(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')), '-'))),3389),greaterOrEquals(int(last(split(first(field('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]')), '-'))),3389)) , 'false')]",
                          "equals": "true"
                        }
                      },
                      "greater": 0
                  },
                  {
                    "not": {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
                      "notEquals": "*"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "not": {
                      "field": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/securityRules/destinationPortRanges[*]",
                      "notEquals": "3389"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
```