# Need to enforce date format correctly as MM/DD/YYYY input via Azure Policy for VM Creation in a Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-policy

I wrote this below Azure Policy to enforce a Termination Date Tag while manually creating a VM inside a Subscription which worked fine as expected. But the format of Date input is set to MM/DD/YYY but I am unable to set MM input to be valid for say next 2 or months only and also it is accepting inputs more than 12 as well as expected. Need guidance how to set it up correctly please.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachines"
        },
        {
          "field": "tags['TerminationDate']",
          "notMatch": "['##/##/####']"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
```

Comment: `tags['TerminationDate']` is a `string`, not `date`. You can put whatever you want, validation wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Dates in JSON are in ISO8601 format ie `YYYY-MM-DD`. That's [a standard, IETF RFC7493](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7493#section-4.3). Where did `TerminationDate` come from and why isn't it in ISO8601 ?

Comment: hi @harshavmb  ,
i need this to be done this way only with this already known tag to be mandate.
Is there any other parameter i can add to get this sorted with this tag in enforced.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is a predefined/existing tag and is supposed to be used in MM/DD/YYYY format only while enforcing policy , that is why i modified my policy in this way. I also tried to use UTC but it doesnt work for enforcing values in MM/DD/YYYY format. I just now need to make sure if someone puts input in MM then it should be greater than 13 for making actual sense.

Comment: If it's predefined why are you trying to check its format? UTC has no meaning in dates. There's no time offset in a date. There's no  `2022-07-15 +07:00`

Comment: Sorry if i didn't cleared it correctly @PanagiotisKanavos
this Tag was predefined but its value wasnt , so users were able to put dates in any format which i enforced to MM/DD/YYYY as per policy defined, just need to redefine it for MM to take correct values only which i am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The resulting policy will be fairly complex, but I think it is possible.

Key Elements I would look into:

- use the `split` function to validate the date parameters separately. This can also be used to enforce that the month is between 1-12
- use the `utcNow` function to check that the passed date is within a given timeframe. Could be combined with `split`, but I would probably just add two months to `utcNow` and compare that to the input. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/issues/388

I would recommend that you look into some of the built in policies to see if they do similar things that you want. You can learn a lot from the syntax. For example: [Azure Policy Support for Port Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728227/azure-policy-support-for-port-ranges/60728388#60728388)

Comment: thank you, i will try to see if i can achieve it this way and share feedback with you as well :)
@alex ait